# Changing form select class when any option is selected apart from one

Tags: javascript, jquery

so i have a working feature that when a user selects any option on my select input, will change the selects class.

This works fine, but what i want is that if the user selects the first option again, then the class gets changed back.

the first option is set as a placeholder, i cant give it a value as i only want the information to be posted if any other options are selected.

I also cant set the input as disabled as i want the user to be able to reselect it after, incase they dont want to post that data.

its a long check list and i am posting the data as an array.

here is a jsfiddle to what i currently have:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/SD7cd/1/
```

Code:

```
<select id="sel1" class="selectoption" name="desc[]">
    <option selected="selected">Select an option...</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("sel1").onchange = function() {
if(this.value != null && this.value != undefined)
{
    this.className = "selectoption-okay";
}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the .selectedIndex property over the value like this:

```
document.getElementById("sel1").onchange = function () {
    this.className = (this.selectedIndex != 0) ? "selectoption-okay":"selectoption";
};
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yjzPK/)**

One problem when you used `if(this.value != null && this.value != undefined)` is that the first option will have a value even though you didn't explicitly assign it. An option element's value will default to its contents if no value is expressly given, no it won't ever be null or undefined.

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option):

> The textual content of this attribute represents the label explaining
>   the option. If it is not defined, its default value is the text
>   content of the element.

Comment: perfect! many thanks! i need to look into this method instead of using if statements

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, When you select the option `Select an option...`, if you have not assigned the `value=''` then `Select an option...` will be taken as a value.

So Added

```
<option selected="selected" value="">Select an option...</option>
                           ^^^^^^^^
```

HTML:

```
 <select id="sel1" class="selectoption" name="desc[]">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Select an option...</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
 </select>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("sel1").onchange = function() {
   this.className = "selectoption";    
   if(this.value != '' )
   {
    this.className = "selectoption-okay";
   }
 };
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/SD7cd/4/**